# Postgres SELECT 2 columns into 1 combined column without null values

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have 2 columns in which one column always has non-null values but the other might have null values:

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| v1 | null |
| v2 | v3 |

I know I can combine 2 columns into 1 like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(array[c1, c2]) as c3 FROM ...
```

Which forms a single column c3:

| c3 |
| --- |
| v1 |
| null |
| v2 |
| v3 |

But I would like to be able to select into 1 column without null values. The only way I can think of is by selecting from my select statement:

```
SELECT c3 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(array[c1, c2]) as c3 FROM ...)
WHERE c3 IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a cross join against a values clause:

```
select distinct x.col
from the_table t
  cross join lateral ( values (t.c1), (t.c2)) as x(col)
where x.col is not null;
```

A UNION might actually be faster, but gets a bit clumsy if you have more than two columns:

```
select x.col
from (
  select c1  as col
  from the_table t
  where c1 is not null
  union 
  select c2
  from the_table t
  where c2 is not null
) x
```

Comment: actually, if i have another condition, where can i put that in the query? like right now my query that gets null values is something like:
`SELECT DISTINCT unnest(array[c1, c2]) as c3 FROM table WHERE c4 = $1`